# Can't hear input sound in keyboard swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, keyboard

I just to want to hear keyboard input sound in my application.

I added

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().playInputClick()
```

to my app Delegate but I'm still not hearing keyboard sounds.

How can I enable it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)` instead of `UIDevice.currentDevice().playInputClick()`.

Comment: Actually I tried it but it's not worked too. I am using it in updateSearchResultsForSearchController. Is This Wrong ?

Comment: func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
UIDevice.currentDevice().playInputClick()
}